# Can't figure out how the symfony assets works in combination with lessphp

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, less, php-5.6

I just started to work into symfony framework.
I created an starting app with symfony and wanted to install bootstrap 3.3.5 with it.
Bit I figured out that it is not working as expected.
As the next step I installed Leafo Less.php.
To add support for bootstrap > 3.2 I installed oyejorge/less.php with wrapper for the leafo lessc compiler.

I registered it in config.yml with the following lines:

## Assetic Configuration

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        lessphp:
            file: %kernel.root_dir%/../src/HomeBundle/Assets/Filter/lessc.php
            apply_to: "\.less$"
            # Formatter options: compressed, lessjs, classic
            formatter: "compressed"
            preserve_comments: false
        cssrewrite: ~
```

so far the commands work.
Next step was, according to the explanations at http://isometriks.com/using-less-with-symfony2 telling me I need to references the style sheet.
So I added into the template the content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
        {% stylesheets '@HomeBundle/Resources/less/bootstrap.less' %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}">
        {% endstylesheets %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Everytime that I call the controller I get the message:

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "_assetic_5bb3373_0" as such route does not exist.") in base.twig at line 8.

Don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Where is my mistake?
Any help is appreceated.

Comment: php app/console cache:clear ?

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. The Error dissapeared, but no css output was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Assetic you need to use the "app/console assetic:dump" command to generate the css/less/js files. This will also copy them to the web folder to make them accessible.

Once you have called this command check the web/css folder to see if your compiled less is in there.

If you are not running in the dev environment (using the app_dev.php in your urls) then you need to specify the production environment when running the command "app/console assetic:dump --env=prod"

Comment: One solution was to clear the cache and then dump the stuff as suggested with assetic.